# Returned data is not display?

Tags: php, laravel, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Cv0.png)Returned data is not display

**Web.route**

```
//Backend Route

Route::post('/admin-dashboard','AdminController@dashboard');
```

**Migration file**

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('adminid');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('password');


        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down() {
    Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
}
```

**Controller file**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

session_start();

class AdminController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return view('admin.admin_login');

    }

    public function show_dashboard() {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }

    public function dashboard(Request $request) {
        $admin_username=$request->admin_name;
        $admin_passwoard=md5($request->admin_passwoard);


        $result=DB::table('admins')
            ->where('name',$admin_username)
            ->where('password',$admin_passwoard)

            ->first();

        dd($result)
    }
}
```

It goes to the correct page but is not displaying any data or any error.
Also it shows the return value and if a session is created then it does not login instead it executes the else statement.

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Only add the function and route in which you are having problem and remove the other code or add a comment on that line where you are having issue.

Comment: In which function, you have problem?

Comment: Its better use Die and Dump --> dd($result) function in laravel instead of exit() and print_r() functions.

Comment: Why you start session in Controller?

Comment: by using dd() is also showig  null

Answer (score 0):

In laravel there are three method to pass data to view

The first is **With**

```
 public function show_dashboard() {
        $data = array('name' => 'sample name',
                      'date' => date('Y-m-d'));  
        return view('admin.dashboard')->with($data);
    }
```

The socond method is **Compact**

```
public function show_dashboard() {
        $name = 'sample name';
        $date = date('Y-m-d'); 
        return view('admin.dashboard',compact('name', 'date'));
    }
```